# Nested table not taking?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have been trying to run the following SQL but it will not work am I missing something obvious or understood this wrong?

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ACTOR_QUOTES(
  2  ACTORID CHAR(5),
  3  QUOTES AQ_NT
  4  ) NESTED TABLE QUOTES STORE AS ACTOR_QUOTES_NT
  5  /
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ACTOR_QUOTES(
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


SQL> CREATE TABLE ACTOR_QUOTES(
  2  ACTORID CHAR (5),
  3  QUOTES AQ_NT,
  4  ) NESTED TABLE QUOTES STORE AS ACTOR_QUOTES_NT
  5  /
) NESTED TABLE QUOTES STORE AS ACTOR_QUOTES_NT
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters, there is no `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` in Oracle. You have to use `CREATE TABLE`. The replace option only works for views, packages, procedures, etc.

Also, not sure why you have numbers before each column name in your table (ex. 2 ACTORID CHAR(5)). They shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the insertion of the code there as I have also tried in as just CREATE TABLE 'SQL> CREATE TABLE ACTOR_QUOTES(
  2  ACTORID CHAR (5),
  3  QUOTES AQ_NT,
  4  ) NESTED TABLE QUOTES STORE AS ACTOR_QUOTES_NT
  5  /'

Comment: Maybe it would help you to look at an example: http://psoug.org/reference/nested_tab.html

Comment: The numbers are prompts from SQLPlus when entering a multi-line command.

Comment: The `REPLACE` option basically doesn't work for objects that consume space, such as tables and indexes.  Objects that are not segments but are essentially definitions stored in actual tables can be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE OR REPLACE does not work on tables. Also your field name should be "NESTED TABLE QUOTES" though ideally I'd go for nested_table_quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you have a comma after the second column definition, which is immediately followed (on the next line) by the closing parenthesis.  Because of the comma, the parser is expecting another column or constraint definition.  Remove it.

Comment: Thanks for that, comma means more to come!